# Select (Drop-Down) not displaying in JQueryUI Accordion

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-ui-accordion

Have a standard JQuery accordion, and a standard form.  But within the accordion, none of the select menus appear in any browser.

Searched and searched.. and can't seem to find a solution to this.  Everything else works beautifully.. just that the selects simple don't appear.

When I view the HTML output with FireBug (or any other inspection tool) the HTML for the select menus are there... and they look fine.  They also work OUTSIDE the accordion.

Any suggestions?

```
<h4>Contact Information</h4>
<div>
   <p>
      <input name="address_1" type="text" required="required" id="clientInfoForm_address_1" form="clientInfoForm" placeholder="Address 1 - REQUIRED" tabindex="80" size="40" maxlength="253"><br>
      <input name="address_2" type="text" id="clientInfoForm_address_2" form="clientInfoForm" placeholder="Address 2" tabindex="90" size="40" maxlength="253"><br>
      <input name="address_3" type="text" id="clientInfoForm_address_3" form="clientInfoForm" placeholder="Address 3" tabindex="100" size="40" maxlength="253">
      <br>
      <input name="city" type="text" required="required" id="city" form="clientInfoForm" placeholder="City - REQUIRED" tabindex="110" maxlength="253">
      <select>
             <option value="" selected>State</option>
             <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
             <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
             <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
             <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
             ... 
      </select>
</div>
```

Standard stuff.. and the input text fields look fine, `just no SELECT`.

Comment: Hmm... This is entirely unique to me?  Wow.. I don't believe it!  :)

Comment: did you work this, i just found it too

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working out that it was to do with the ui's default z-index used on the dropdown when open:

```
  .ui-front {
    z-index: 100;
 }
```